# divergence rate for a sum involving log

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I ma trying to see how $$S_m=\sum_{h=1}^{m-1}\frac{m-h}{h}\log h$$

Numerically I get the following graph, after trying different simple "guessing" for the rate I think that the rate is not a simple function.

[image]

The red line is $m (\log m)^{1.6} $ and the blue if the sum ...

I appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), we get
$$
\sum_{h=1}^{m-1}\frac{m-h}{h}\log(h)=\small m\left(\frac{\log(m)^2}2-\log(m)+1+\gamma_1\right)-\frac{\log(2\pi)}2-\frac{\log(m)}{12m}+O\left(\frac{\log(m)}{m^3}\right)
$$
where $\gamma_1=-0.07281584548367672486$ is one of the [Stieltjes Constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

So using the asymptotic approximation
$$
m\left(\frac{\log(m)^2}2-\log(m)+1+\gamma_1\right)-\frac{\log(2\pi)}2
$$
the error gets smaller as $m$ gets larger.

---

**Computation of $\boldsymbol{\gamma_1}$**
$$
\gamma_1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}k-\frac{\log(n)^2}2\right)
$$
The Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula says that
$$
\begin{align}
\small\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}k
&\small=\frac{\log(n)^2}2+\gamma_1+\frac{\log(n)}{2n}-\frac{\log(n)-1}{12n^2}+\frac{6\log(n)-11}{720n^4}-\frac{60\log(n)-137}{15120n^6}\\
&\small+\frac{140\log(n)-363}{33600n^8}-\frac{1386\log(n)-7129}{332640n^{10}}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^{12}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Setting $n=100$, we get $\gamma_1$ to over $20$ places.

Comment: Excellent! Many Thanks :-)

Comment: Oh you are amazing!

Comment: May I ask how do you proceed with finding $\beta,\alpha$? Since these values make the approximation substantially good...

Comment: @Math-fun: I have added sections on computing the constants.

Comment: @Math-fun: I just realized that $\alpha=\frac{\log(2\pi)}2$.

Comment: Many thanks! this is great.

Comment: @robjohn Really solid answer.  It shows the beauty of application of the E-M sum!  +1 wish there were a +2

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks to [Chris's sister](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22821082#22821082) for pointing out that one of the constants was a Stieltjes constant.